# Set JavaScript events in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, attributes, browser

I have a WebBrowser control and try to set onclick and href attributes on all links.

```
foreach (HtmlElement link in webBrowser1.Document.Links)
{
      link.SetAttribute("href", "http://www.google.com");
      link.SetAttribute("onclick", "return false;");
}
```

It works well. When i out source code of outer html i see that attributes was exist.
But JavaScript code does not work. Why and how i can force WebBrowser control to execute javascript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[onclick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752306(VS.85).aspx) is a property of type IDispatch. You can assign a function with no parameter to the property or add an attribute to HTML and let the parser to do this for you but you can't assign a string to it via DOM.

You can either pass an object that implements IDispatch and the default method (dispid=0) to the property, or use IHTMLElement2::attachEvent to attach an event handler. If you are using Microsoft's class libraries, you can use Microsoft's wrappers like HtmlElement.AttachEventHandler in Windows Forms and HtmlElement.Attachevent in Silverlight.